# After regex finding, how do i replace a part of the result in Notepad++?

Tags: regex, notepad++

How do i add a space character before the last occurring "ms" in every line? I tried the regex find but how do i replace only the last part of that found string?

Am i missing out on syntax or a setting that i need to use/enable?

[image: part-replace-regex]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use capturing groups. Replace

```
:\s+([0-9]+)ms
```

with

```
: $1 ms
```